# How can I make Selenium tests inside my JSF project?

Tags: jsf, testing, selenium, integration-testing

I have quite big JSF 1.2 project and I want to write some integration tests to it.
The perfect situation will be, when I can run these tests from my project and it opens my browser and makes all the actions (with Selenium), which are written in my test cases. Ofc opening browser is not required when It will run these tests anyway :)

I've tried a few possibilities, anyway I still can't attach any selenium library to my project and I realized that I just dont know where to start - can you give me some direction?

Comment: What kind of test are you trying to do? Selenium is for UI test, you really need to have a browser. If you don't need a browser, for unit testing you can use JUnit and Mockito. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**might help you ,
you can write you test logic inside test method**

```
package com.test;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

public class test1 {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Ignore
    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        // your test code 

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
            fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
    }

    private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
            driver.findElement(by);
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**you just need call test1 class which you want to test it .**
 **it will be automatically working on it .**

Comment: I have the same problem. can you provide any references/tutorials.